# Effective way to detect NAT network inside of Linux

Tags: linux, networking, nat, vps, kernel

In Ubuntu I need to detect if the Network ip address is a NAT system, (not need STUN )

I thought check the ip class range type like this: [Check if IP address is in private network space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41240761/check-if-ip-address-is-in-private-network-space)

But I saw another way, using NETLINK_ROUTE get the local ip system from the route table of kernel network stack

Compare that ip with the external ip routable, if are equal, the network is not a nat system

In Perl I found a module IO::Socket::Netlink::Route, I tested and work

https://metacpan.org/pod/release/PEVANS/Socket-Netlink-Route-0.05/lib/IO/Socket/Netlink/Route.pm

But reading about /sbin/ip route:

```
All operations with the ip route command are atomic, so each command will return either RTNETLINK answers
```

http://linux-ip.net/html/tools-ip-route.html

About Rtnetlink

```
Rtnetlink allows the kernel's routing tables to be read
```

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/rtnetlink.7.html

I already using /sbin/ip route to get the main ip of active network, so I want to avoid install another module, and just used ip route for doing the detection NAT system.

Is my aproach correct?

Comment: Do you mean something like `ip route get 1.2.3.4` and look at the selected source address?